# Possible to add a method to an existing Java class using ASM?

Tags: java, extension-methods, java-bytecode-asm

I want to add a method to an existing class I don't have control of, e.g. have a method toList() in the Stream class of Java8. Question is whether this can be done using ASM. I guess so.

My more specific question is whether I can create something like a jar that contains the extension method (like to class Stream). I can then add the jar to my project and the toList() method becomes visible in the Java8 Stream class. From what I understand the extension method could only be weaved in at runtime or when I have a runtime that can do this (like Groovy, Kotlin, Scala). I know there is project Lombok, but it has only a plugin for eclipse that supports the corresponding feature. The plugin for IntelliJ does not support this specific feature.

Comment: to add a method ... the obvious way would be to extend the class, and add that method in the childclass

Comment: Yes, that's right. What I want, though, is something like an extension method (subclassing class String won't help) as in Groovy, Kotlin, Scala, Smalltalk, C# and other languages without having to revert to any of these languages.

Comment: You can 't subclass string, because it is an immutable class. You can, however, create a composite object

Comment: That is correct, but the question is about extension methods and not about subclassing.

Comment: Indeed, but your example: 'changing String' is basically not something you should (try to) do at all.

Comment: AFAIK, Kotlin's extension functions do not modify existing Java sources - they cannot add new fields, access private variables, etc. Instead, all extension methods are declared as `static` - this is just a syntax sugar.

Comment: @JustACluelessNewbie: That is correct. But just a simple extension method as in Ruby or Groovy would already be very useful ;-)

Comment: There seems to be a fundamental misunderstanding. You can do anything you want with ASM as said library supports arbitrary bytecode transformations, but in the end that's nothing more than reading a byte array and producing a byte array. Your actual question is about changing the Java environment to use a modified class which has nothing to do with ASM. There are plenty of different ways, different in what you can do and what not.

Answer (score 0):

I try to answer question in order:

Q1: I want to add a method to an existing class I don't have control of 
Yes. You can add a new method/remove an existing method to an existing class, no matter what the original class is. 
A simple sample code with ASM is to add

```
ClassReader cr = new ClassReader(is);//'is' is inputstream to some bytecode.
ClassWriter cw = new SomeClassWriter(ClassWriter.COMPUTE_FRAMES）
cr.accept(cw, 0);

class SomeClassWriter extends ClassVisitor{
    ....
    @Override
    public MethodVisitor visitEnd(){
         MethodVisitor mv = cw.visitMethod(...); 
         toListMethodNode.accept(mv). 
         super.visitEnd().
    }
```

}

Q2:  whether I can create something like a jar that contains the extension method (like to class Stream)

To enable the new generated bytecode, you need to load the bytecode via aclass loader. It is not related to whether package it as jar or not, and the new generated bytecode is useless if it is not loaded by a class loader. 
The point here is that: a normal class loader does not allow to load the bytecode with same symbol name twice. Therefore, the new bytecode class (with toList() method) has the same class name, you have to load it in another classLoader.  The exception is using *Unsafe.defineAnonymousClass()* which i do not think you will use.